# Firestore Security rules - detect when a rule denies access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have my Firestore rules written and tested. Now I would like to detect potential hackers who get denied access by the rules and put them in a block list which would then be enforced by my rules.

Question: is there a way to know what users get denied access to Firestore? Ideally I would have a Cloud Function triggered when a rule denies access, this function would then add the misbehaving user to list of blocked users.

Reason: there are plenty of them. But the two first ones are that 1) rules actually cost me reads and more importantly 2) the more tries a hacker has the more likely he is to find a hole, blocking him would force him to re-create an account and waste some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase provides no logging or monitoring for denied security rules.  You could file this as a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).